# svelte invalidate not working with custom identifier

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In svelte/SvelteKit I have a load that is *not a fetch*. The goal is to reload this "non-fetch" load with a button in UI.

According to Svelte documentation for [depends](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#input-methods-depends), I should be able to use `invalidate` with a `custom identifier`, and "register" the custom identifier in the load?

Something like this:

```js
export const load: PageLoad = function( { depends }){
    depends(
        'my:customurl'
    );
...
```

The `custom identifier` needs to be formated properly, and `beforecolon:aftercolon` should be legal format.

I am unable to get any reaction in the load when calling `invalidate` or `invalidateAll` from `+page.svelte`.
Reproducable code (with hardcoded dummy data return) goes like this:

`+page.ts:`

```js
import type { PageLoad } from './$types';

 export const load: PageLoad = function( { depends }){
    depends(
        'my:customurl'
    );
    console.log("load is triggered...")
    const someJson = JSON.parse(`{"someData":"${new Date().toISOString()}"}`);
    return {
        theData : someJson
    }
}
```

`+page.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from "./$types";
    import { invalidate } from '$app/navigation';
    import { invalidateAll } from '$app/navigation';

    export let data: PageData;
    $: ({theData} = data)
  
    function reload(){
        invalidate('my:customurl');
    };
    function reloadAll(){
        invalidateAll();
    };

</script>

<div>  
  <section>
    <h3>Actions</h3>
    <button on:click={reload}>Reload</button>
    <button on:click={reloadAll}>Reload All</button>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Data</h3>
    <div>{theData.someData}</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I have also done the same with a `+page.server.ts`, but the result is the same.

I am using the same custom identifier `my:customurl` both in `+page.svelte` and `+page.ts` (or alt `+page.server.ts`).

I can tell the `invalidate` or `invalidateAll` is not working because the date is not changing when the buttons are clicked (The date is changing on browser page reload).

What do I need to do to get invalidate working for a non-fetch load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can tell the `invalidate` or `invalidateAll` is not working because `console.log("load is triggered...")` is not written when clicking either button.

You might be looking in the wrong place: After initial load, the code will run on the client, i.e. there will be no output on the server.

This works just fine for me.

Try actually changing the data:

```js
const someJson = JSON.parse(`{"someData":"${new Date().toISOString()}"}`);
```

Comment: I changed my code as you suggest so that data actually changes. The buttons triggering invalidate and invalidateAll is still not having an effect. Data unchanged. If I reload the browser page, the data changes.

Comment: I have just taken the code as is, if it does not work on your end, something outside the given code might be interfering. I also tried to upgrade all packages to the latest version to make sure the problem is not some regression, it still worked after that.

Comment: I adjusted my question to incorporate the smarter "new Date" trick to get data actually changing. Makes it safer and easier to observe :)

Comment: Ok. Useful to know the code should work, and works elswhere...  I will investigate further on my end.

Comment: Ok, so I figured something out: when I had the two code files in a subfolder of routes, my code sample does not work.  When I have them in root of routes it does work. So why does it not work in a sub page?

Comment: I have them in a folder `src/routes/depends` and that works the same as having them directly in `src/routes`.

Comment: So I moved them back in subfolder, the same as it was before and not working, and now it works there also. I have no idea why. Anyway, all good I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some dev server desynchronization issue.

Comment: Probably something like that. I physically moved the files, so pretty sure no code was changed.